# Can I set a variable as a max value on an input element?

Tags: javascript, html, input, max

I have a canvas on my page and a few `input[type="range"]` tags to play with it. What I need, is to set the value of the `max` attribute as a JS variable.

I've tried to:

- Set it directly in the HTML like that: `<input type="range" id="y" max="canvas.height">`
- Set it in Javascript, but I don't know how to set the `max` attribute in JS, so I tried something like that: `id("y").max = canvas.height; // id() is my utility function`

So basically what I'm asking you is to tell me what I'm doing wrong, or how to set the `max`/`min` in JS.

I've looked here:

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max

P.S. I know how to achieve this in jQuery, (using .attr) but I don't want to bring jQuery to my project just because of one attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that, as jQuery is built on vanilla JS, anything that jQuery is doing can be accomplished with plain JavaScript.  In this particular instance, you are looking for [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```js
const myInput = document.querySelector('some css selector that matches your input'); // you can get this any way you want
myInput.setAttribute('max', canvas.height);
```

I don't believe there is a way to reference a JS variable directly in HTML, so I believe JS is your answer.  That said, perhaps another poster can provide some different approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot on that method, sorry, my bad. I'll probably accept your answer, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do that yet. So maybe after 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Pleach check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#:%7E:text=Sets%20the%20value%20of%20an,an%20attribute%2C%20call%20removeAttribute()%20.). I hope this will be helpful.

So you can do like this:

```
Element.setAttribute('max', 'canvas.height');
```

Comment: I believe this would attempt to set the `max` attribute to the _string_ `"canvas.height"`, not to the value of `canvas.height`.